# Client certificate common name? Subject alternative name?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ssl-client-authentication

I want to secure client server communication. I want both the server and the clients identify/authenticate each other.

I would like to know, how to set common name and subject alternative names for clients on server? As we know, on client side, we can use hostname verifier, But how to do that on server side?

Thanks!

Comment: On the client side, your certificates will be either for a device (ex: IoT) or a person (ex: user of a browser). It depends who delivers the client certificates: you or some external public CA?

Comment: It's external public CA. I think on server side, we cannot got hostname or domain name of client, so things will be different from client side verify(useally we compare the target hostname with server sans and cns).  Should it be that: on server side, we ask user to configurate sans and cns they trusts, and then compare them with sans and cns of client certificates?